# OpenSearch knn index similarity search not returning any hits

Tags: knn, opensearch

I am trying to set up a proof of concept showing how the OpenSearch knn index similarity search works with text I copied from Wikipedia. I am using Python and opensearchpy to send and retrieve data from the OpenSearch instance. I am not getting any errors so I think I am setting things up the correct way but when I try to query the index with a simple one word search term I get a successful response with no hits back. I am pretty new to OpenSearch in general so the problem may be super obvious and I am just missing it.

setting up index

```
index_name = 'knn-test'
index_body = {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "knn": "true",
      "knn.algo_param.ef_search": 100
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "encoded_text": {
          "type": "knn_vector",
          "dimension": 768,
          "method": {
            "name": "hnsw",
            "space_type": "innerproduct",
            "engine": "faiss",
            "parameters": {
              "ef_construction": 512,
              "m": 16
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

response = opensearch_py_connection.indices.create(index_name, body=index_body)
print('\nCreating index:')
print(response)
```

Encoding the text and loading it into the index

```
word_embedding_model = sentence_models.Transformer("sentence-transformers/paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1", max_seq_length=256)
pooling_model = sentence_models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())
model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])

id = 1
for text in text_list:

    encoded_text = model.encode(text, convert_to_tensor=False)

    document = {
        'encoded-text': encoded_text
    }

    response = opensearch_py_connection.index(
        index = "knn-test",
        body = document,
        id = id,
        refresh = True
    )

    print('\nAdding document:')
    print(response)
    id = id+1
```

Encode and ask basic query

```
query = "ship"

encoded_query = model.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=False)

query_body = {
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "knn": {
      "encoded_text": {
        "vector": encoded_query,
        "k": 2
      }
    }
  }
}

response = opensearch_py_connection.search(
    body = query_body,
    index = "knn-test"
)
print('\nSearch results:')
print(response)
```

print out of the query is as follows:

```
Search results:
{'took': 7, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

My guess is that I am formatting the body of one of the opensearchpy calls the wrong way but I have not been able to find out why exactly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your document with model.encode('your document'). query a record to make sure it has the imbedded number. then you can do the text query